# What is the equivalent of CUDNN convolutionBackwardFilter in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, cudnn

I'm trying to port some code that is using CUDNN on Tensorflow. Most of it aws very easy to port, but I'm having an issue porting cudnnConvolutionBackwardFilter to Tensorflow. I tried using `conv2d` and `conv2d_transpose` but none of them works for this configuration. That means I have inputs in the form of `[N, V, V, C]` and `[N, F, F, K]` and I need an output in `[V-F, V-F, C, K]`. I though of doing a loop doing all the convolutions and summing the results, but I didn't find a way of doing such a loop in the tensorflow graph.

How can I translate such code to Tensorflow ?

Comment: I have seen some Op called `Conv2DBackpropFilter`, maybe it does something similar to what you want to achieve?

Comment: @sygi You're absolutely right. It's not in the documentation, but it's accessible with ```conv2d_backprop_filter```. Could you post it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Op called [Conv2DBackpropFilter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py#L30) (accessible with `conv2d_backprop_filter` from Python), which is defined in C++ part of the code and it may be what you are looking for.